# How to get push notification message in android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive the push notification message and send the notification message but i am getting the null value not receive any message.

**Below code**

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    Log.d("push","msg type: " + messageType);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
        } else if (!extras.isEmpty() && GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
            Log.d("push notify msg: ", extras.toString());
            sendNotification(extras.toString());
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: refer this link might be help you: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 3):

Create a receiver and declare it in manifest.

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),XYZIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
 }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.companyname.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="PKG_NAME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Meta Data Tag:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Permissions:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.vuliv.player.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.vuliv.player.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```

Now you can add your code to XYZIntentService to get GCM notification.

For any query feel free to raise.

Comment: Hi Vibhor, i gave above details mention but still i am receiving the null message only...

Answer (score 1):

[Follow this link it is a sample project of GCM provided by GOOGLE it will help you](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm)